# Reliably get non-localized output from a system command on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, localization, iis-express, spawn

`iisexpresstray` is a helper app that comes with IIS Express and shows info about running instances of this server. I wanted to learn how it works, so I decompiled this .NET program with ILSpy. In particular, my attention was drawn by a piece of code that runs a system command, namely `netsh http show servicestate view=requestq`:

```
string text;
using (Process process = new Process()) {
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "http show servicestate view=requestq";
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.Start();
    text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Nothing special so far, but then this code parses the output of this command expecting to find English substrings like `"Process IDs:"` and `"Registered URLs:"`, which are there only if the command's output isn't localized. And this somehow works, even on localized Windows. Moreover, `iisexpresstray` relies on this behavior.

So how does this work? When I'm simply copypasting this snippet to LINQPad running on localized Windows, I expectedly see localized results. Setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` doesn't change anything.

Comment: Perhaps `iisexpresstray` is running in local system context rather than the user's context?  You could check this with Task Manager.

Comment: It shows my user name in the "User" column of Task Manager.

Comment: OK.  Never mind then. :-)